# Проблема с кодировками

Tags: java, кодировка, поток-ввода, filewriter

Имеется утилита, которая запускает батники, которые в свою очередь собирают инфу с помощью утилиты `wmic` и потом с них форматирует отчет на рабочий стол.

Программа в общем-то ничего сложного не делает, обычная работа с файлами и текстом, если упростить, но проблема в том, что при чтении файла (в файле точно не `UTF-8`, word определил кодировку, как `Юникод`) поэтому геморрой с обработкой информации, с этим я в общем-то справился, вот только на ноутах она выдает дичь, где используется кириллица.

К слову к примеру если в строку я записываю кириллицу сам, то всё ок. Проблема только с файлом. Вот 1 из методов.

```
void networkAdapterGet() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(NETWORK_ADAPTER_INFO_PATH));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(TEMP_RESULT_FILE_PATH, true))) {
        line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null){
            if (line.length() > 1){
                line = trimSpaces(line);
                line = networkAdapterProcessing(line);
                if (!line.equals("")){
                    result.append(line);
                    result.append(lineSeparator);
                }
            }
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        writer.write("Сетевые устройства:");
        writer.write(lineSeparator);
        writer.write(result.toString());
        writer.write(lineSeparator);
        writer.write(lineSeparator);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Скорее всего зря повелся на`FileReader`/`Writer` и думаю основная проблема, как раз таки в `Reader`'е. Пошаманил с кодировками на открытии и получил фигу, упало как раз таки из-за несовпадения кодировок, можно конечно перебрать вариантов там пара всего, но хотелось бы узнать можно ли как-то это дело исправить. Это пока единственный мешающий/раздражающий баг на данном этапе разработки утилитки.

Comment: похоже что word не очень хороший советчик кодировок

Comment: не исключено, но хотелось бы узнать в каком направлении тонуть. Reader'а или пытаться шаманить с новым методом и переделать попробовать. Технически там на русском только будет для bluetooth'а и модуля wi-fi так что технически я вообще могу подменить эту хрень, но фактически там костылей и так хватает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно писать в той кодировке, которая читается клиентом. Чтобы указать кодировку надо заменить `FileWriter` на

```
new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(TEMP_RESULT_FILE_PATH), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

если  кодировка `UTF_8` не подходит, то можно попробовать `KOI-8` или `CP1251`, или другая кодировка, которая поддерживает кирилицу, например `CP866`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, обязательно попробую.

Comment: Увы, стало только хуже, но спасибо буду копать в данном направлении дальше. Возможно попробую OutputStreamReader/Writer вместо своих BufferedReader/Writer. Хотя бы уже не совсем в болоте. Тут дело в том, что изменение кодировки полностью портит кириллицу в строке, которую я использую для форматирования, то есть дописываю сам, поэтому думаю, что можно будет либо поиграться с кодировками для самой строки, либо поиграться с разными Reader/Writer группами. Вот не думал что кодировки могут так сильно подгадить, когда только начинал писать. Вроде бы и баг-то не критичный, но раздражает не слабо.

Answer (score 1):

Очень помог ответ, Roman C. Получилась немного громоздкая конструкция со всеми этими обертками, но вроде бы работает осталось поправить другой метод, а именно networkAdapterProcessing(), чтобы корректно отображался результат, да и остальные методы можно оставить без изменений потому, что проблема только в сетевых устройствах, но вот решение самой проблемы с кодировками получилась весьма интересной хотя бы для меня, я еще пока только учусь.

```
try(BufferedReader reader = 
                new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                                new FileInputStream(NETWORK_ADAPTER_INFO_PATH), "Unicode"));
        BufferedWriter writer = 
                new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(
                                new FileOutputStream(TEMP_RESULT_FILE_PATH, true), "Unicode"))){
```

Так вот для того, чтобы определить кодировку достаточно было открыть файл клятым блокнотом и жамкнуть "Сохранить как", чтобы убедиться в том, что это Юникод. Причем пробовал вначале пересохранить в UTF-8, но там была полная борода. Сейчас конечно из-за того, что открывает с помощью другого инструмента сменилась и сама структура получаемой строки немного, но это уже мелочи по сравнению с раздражающей меня ошибкой с кодировкой. Как это у меня обычно и бывает проблема была в сути своей совсем не сложной, но мозги она заклинила неслабо. В будущем думаю исправлю, чтобы было все одинаково и не выделялось, но пока надо сделать хотя бы это. Спасибо вам за помощь.