# JSP с подключенными файлами HTML

Tags: java-ee, jsp, кодировка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, только начинаю осваивать jsp и столкнулся со следующей проблемой.
Создал jsp-файл, куда подключаются две страницы html. В странице,именованной header.html должен быть контент на русском языке, указав ссылки на подключаемые страницы получаю некорректную информацию. Подозреваю, что имеются какие то конфликты в кодировке. Прошу понять и простить, если где-то на просторах интернета все-таки можно найти эту инфу. Задаю здесь вопрос, поскольку, самостоятельно не сумел найти решение проблемы.

Это код проблемной страницы:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
фывфыв

</body>
</html>[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
```

Это код с *.jsp:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<%@ include file="../fragment/header.html" %>

    <%@ include file="../fragment/footer.html" %>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S: Прошу прощения, сам пример кода кривой, с совпадающими кодировками аналогичная ситуация

Answer (score 0):

> meta charset="ISO-8859-1"

Полагаю, у Вас просто не совпадают заявленная кодировка и фактическая.
Попробуйте поменять кодировку, а лучше всего используйте везде UTF-8.

Comment: Пробовал, но по-прежнему проблема не решалась.

Comment: Прошу прощения, сам пример кода кривой, с совпадающими кодировками аналогичная ситуация

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что вы выбрали неверную кодировку для символов, которая не содержит кириллицы.

Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/863626/204920) я привёл примеры кодировок с кирилицами.

> если кодировка UTF_8 не подходит, то можно попробовать KOI-8 или CP1251, или другая кодировка, которая поддерживает кирилицу, например CP866.

О кодировках в вэб приложении можно почитать [тут](http://www.skipy.ru/technics/encodings_webapp.html).

> Кодировка, использующаяся для передачи данных, должна совпадать с кодировкой страниц, создаваемых веб-приложением.