# Java - вывод текста с консоли с правильной кодировко

Tags: java

У меня есть проблема, допустим, я делаю программу на Java, которая получает команду которую хочет выполнить пользователь, выполняет её, и получает вывод с консоли. Так то у меня всё работает, с одной проблемой, если в выводе будут русские буквы, то вместо букв будут символы по типу "Џ ¬пвм", и так со всеми русскими буквами, а вывод английских букв проблем не вызывает, не знаю даже как решить эту проблему) Вот мой код:

```
public static String terminalLogger;
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist"); //Какая нибудь команда, допустим будет tasklist
                InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    consoleOutput = ConsoleOutput + "\n" + line; //Запись вывода с консоли в переменную consoleOutput
                }
                reader.close();
```

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/863626/204920) ответ.

Comment: Как вариант, заменить стандартный шрифт консоли на тот, который умеет кириллицу.